# Primefaces: PanelGrid in Datatable LiveScroll

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there anyone who tried that? When it loads more panelGrid, table just duplicates them.
[this picture result of that simple code block](http://d1211.hizliresim.com/13/2/fkcgz.png). Upper side shows how should it be rendered in a proper way but it goes wrong like at the down side.

```
         <p:dataTable liveScroll="true" value="#{PanelController.panelList2}" var="GridPanel" scrollable="true" scrollRows="20" scrollHeight="100" rows="5">
               <p:column>
                   <p:panelGrid>
                       <p:row>
                           <p:column>
                               <h:outputText value="ehehe"></h:outputText>
                           </p:column>
                       </p:row>
                   </p:panelGrid>
               </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: could you extend your question with a working example and add more description like, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i edited my question for more detail.

Comment: Why would you want to use a `<p:panelGrid>` inside of a `<p:dataTable>`? What's your functional requirement for this or is just something you want to add some *good looking* to the items in the datatable? Note that the generated HTML will be a table inside a table and there are better solutions to the monster you're trying to  conceive.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to insert good looking items into dataTable(i need to compose rows columns etc.) How can i do that instead of using panelGrid?

Comment: It would be good to define if you need to use a `<p:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` for your functional requirement. The main difference (on view) is that the `<ui:repeat>` won't wrap all the content inside a table and you're free to write the HTML/JSF code you need inside it.

Comment: Considering my requirements; <ui:repeat> is more suitable. But in PrimeFaces, there is one and only component with liveScroll(infinite-scroll) attribute: <p:dataTable>. It's so hard to handle it but i quite forwarded just one issue remains: panelGrid.

Comment: you can try out primefaces extension library, it supports infinite scrolling through a new component called waypoint. [here](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/waypoint/infiniteScrollingOne.jsf) is the link.

Answer (score 0):

If it was up to me I'd use the p:dataScroller und then use the panelgrid inside that. Take a look at this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/inline.xhtml